# Help with toggle all functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where each element can be toggled open and closed like this

The list is like this:

```
<h2 class="siteDesSubTrigger"> <a href="#">Trigger</a></h2>
<div class="siteDesSubBlock" style="display: none;">
<ul>    
<li>
Sub Content
</li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery is like this

```
$("h2.siteDesSubTrigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; 
    });
```

I need to also add a Expand All/ Collapse All switch but I am having troubles getting this to work properly.  This is what I have so far

```
$("h2.expandAll").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle(function() {
    $("h2.expandAll").text("Collapse All");
    }, function(){
    $("h2.expandAll").text("Expand All");
    });

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".siteDesSubBlock").toggle();
    });
```

but it is really buggy.. like if a panel is already expanded it will close it while opening the rest and.. well it basically doesnt work :P.  Can someone please help me with the proper way to write this function?

Answer (score 0):

The expand all could be rewritten to just use the click handlers of non-active h2's like so:

```
$('h2.siteDesSubTrigger').not('.active').click();
```

And the collapse all could be rewritten to just click active headers, eg.

```
$('h2.siteDesSubTrigger.active').click();
```

By implementing the expand/collapse all buttons like this, you leave each h2 click handler to deal with it's own toggle state and you shouldn't get into consistency issues.

Answer (score 0):

firs of you should do this to make sure the link doesn't do default:

```
$("h2.siteDesSubTrigger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

It works more properly in all browsers than return false

Here is how you do expand all and collapse all.

```
//expand all
$("h2.expandAll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".siteDesSubBlock").addClass("active");
    $(".siteDesSubBlock").slideDown("slow");
});
//collapse all
$("h2.collapseAll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".siteDesSubBlock").removeClass("active");
    $(".siteDesSubBlock").slideUp("slow");
});
```

I put it all on jsfiddle for you to view here: http://jsfiddle.net/jsweazy/MnnAf/